# How to change the image name from the Dockerfile based on the platform?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-image

I am trying to use `Dockerfile` to build docker image.

How can I create a conditional check based on the platform in Dockerfile.

For example,

```
FROM --platform=$BUILDPLATFORM golang:alpine AS build
ARG BUILDPLATFORM

IF ${BUILDPLATFORM} == 'windows'
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0
ELSE 
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0-windowsservercore-ltsc2022
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're better off fixing the base image so this isn't necessary, possibly building your own base image. But to do it this way, here's an option that requires you define all of the platforms:

```
ARG BUILDOS
ARG BUILDPLATFORM
FROM --platform=$BUILDPLATFORM golang:alpine AS build
# ...

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 as dotnet-base-windows
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0-windowsservercore-ltsc2022 as dotnet-base-linux
FROM dotnet-base-${BUILDOS}
# ...
```

Comment: $BUILDPLATFORM return `linux/amd64` I think you are expecting `linux`

Comment: @jay that was mirroring the example `if` from your question.

Comment: Thank you. Just so I understand why `FROM --platform=$BUILDPLATFORM golang:alpine` is needed when all we need is `BUILDOS`?

Comment: You don't, that part was from your question and kept for context.

Comment: Without that line, the image build fails. The line on the OP is from the docker documentation

Comment: Please post a new question describing what you goal is and provide a [mcve], including a complete Dockerfile, any other supporting files, the commands run, and the output from those commands.